# PDO PHP Form unable to save record

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm scratching my head over this and not sure why this isn't working

I am trying to post info from a form to save the entry in the database, for troubleshooting I am doing a field at a time

Here is my code and the link is `/example.php?device=test`

I have even tried `$_GET['device'] = "test101";` and still no luck.

The database name and login is correct as I have another form that works, knowing this I have copied and pasted the code to this file and changed the details for the table to try help solve my problem.

I'm guessing its something simple that I have over looked.

```
 <?php

 // include database connection
    include 'inc/connect.php';

    try{

        // insert query
        $query = "INSERT INTO repairs SET device=:device";

        // prepare query for execution
        $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

        // bind the parameters
        $stmt->bindParam(':device', $_GET['device']);




        // Execute the query
        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "<div>Record was saved.</div>";
        }else{
            echo mysql_error();
            die('Unable to save record.');
        }

    }

    // show error
    catch(PDOException $exception){
        die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }

?>
```

Comment: you're mixing MySQL APIs here `mysql_error()`

Comment: and sligthly offtopic: GET is not the preferred verb for an INSERT operation. Better use POST.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change `INSERT INTO` to `update`

if you want to update:-

```
 $query = "update repairs SET device=:device";
```

or if you want to insert

```
$query = "INSERT INTO repairs (device)  VALUES (:device)";
```

Comment: Great thanks. but this updates all the rows not insert a new one :/

Comment: thanks for the updated answer but update works and insert don't

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO repairs (device)  VALUES (:device)";

Comment: try this query @RichardRansom

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... SET col=val` is [perfectly valid](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

Comment: @VolkerK Perfectly valid yes. However, if there isn't a record to update, then using UPDATE may fail, I tend to think. Plus, OP is mixing MySQL APIs and will never get the real error as to why their code may have failed.  The person who answered should have made a mention of that.

Comment: @Fred : But all of this isn't part of this answer. a) I don't think it's supposed to be an UPDATE query. The OP says otherwise in the question and there's no WHERE clause; I think that indicates indeed an INSERT. b) An UPDATE not updating any record does not raise an _error_ , numRow() would simply be 0. c) mixing mysql_* and PDO is bad; but still not part of _this_ answer ;-) Conclusion: I'm a bit puzzled why this is the accepted answer....

Comment: @VolkerK Agreed. Yeah, I was going to make a note to the OP about the omitted `WHERE` clause, but feel I would only be wasting my time. I'm also puzzled.

Comment: "would only be wasting my time" I think so, too, but maybe for a different reason ;-) UPDATE came only up in this _answer_, not in the question. My _guess_ is the (unfamiliar?) `INSERT ... SET col=val`syntax made Rahautos jump to the (unfitting) conclusion that the question is about an UPDATE query. In the trade we call that "pulling it out off one's ar...mpit" (just kidding, no offense)

Comment: @VolkerK I've seen these types of questions and answers all too many times to come to the conclusion that by stating otherwise, would amount to nothing, seeing that nobody here besides you and I have been commenting about the question and the answer given. It doesn't "explain" the problem and we'll probably never know the "real" reason neither. I'm jumping out of this question now, *cheers*